# How to mock file to test file upload in rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rspec, rails-4-2-1

I'm trying to test the action to import products from a CSV.

I'm being able to get the first test to pass. The `params[:file]` goes to the controller as a string `"#<StringIO:0x007fc0d40a0bd0>"` which doesn't make my test fail but it isn't the correct behaviour.

The second test I'm getting the following error

```
private method `gets' called for  #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd391de0a00>
```

Here's is my spec (content is the CSV content)

```
  # spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb

  describe 'POST import with file' do
    before do
      post :import, file: file
    end

    context 'with invalid data' do
      subject { Spree::Product.count }
      let(:file) { StringIO.new("") }
      it { is_expected.to eq 0 }
    end

    context 'with valid data' do
      subject { Spree::Product.count }
      let(:file) { ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(params) }

      let(:params) do
        {
          original_filename: 'file.csv',
          content_type: 'text/csv',
          tempfile: StringIO.new(content)
        }
      end

      it { is_expected.to eq 1 }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` to upload a test file, something like this

```
context 'with valid data' do
  subject { Spree::Product.count }
  let(:path_to_file) { Rails.root.join 'spec/fixtures/file.csv' }
  let(:file) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new path_to_file, 'text/csv' }

  it { is_expected.to eq 1 }
end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as using `Rails.root.joi('/some/file')` along with `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new` works a charm

Comment: `fixture_file_upload` is a convenience method provided by Rails for this, FYI.